# Editing Resource Bundle in Intelij does not work with default locale file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Editing Resource Bundle in Intelij does not work with default locale file.
[image: default locale file]

I use spring boot and intelij community. How to add `messages.propperties` to Resource Bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the icon of your file, it looks like it is not marked as **properties** but rather as **plain text**.

Just right click the file and select:

> Mark as Properties

[image]

---

Also, when you have several property files already but they are not combined to bundle, you can right-click several property files and select from the context menu:

> Combine to resource bundle

[image]